# How to get inequality representation of cone give by generators

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming

To be as specific as possible, I have a subspace $I \subset R^{14}$ of dimension $3$ and an $11\times14$ matrix $A$ with linearly independent rows spanning the orthogonal complement of $I$. I have an interest in the cone positively spanned by the columns of $A$ (it can be shown that these columns are positively independent). In particular, I would like to find the inequality representation of this cone (which happens to be pointed). My understanding is that in general this is not a simple problem although I have found a small paper published years ago in J. Matrix Anal and Appl (by Carolyn Dobler) presenting a simple method for doing this, unfortunately requiring that the matrix $A^\prime$ be of full row rank. I was hoping the specific form of $A$ might make it amenable to a similar procedure.

If it would help for me to post the entire matrix I can do that; however, I'm really looking for an approach in a more general context (general dimensions).

Any pointers to relevant areas of research would be appreciated.